# Untrusted pickle source

Tags: python, pickle

From the python docs for [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) :

> Warning The pickle module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust.

What would be an example of pickling and then un-pickling data that would do something malicious? I've only ever used pickle to save objects that don't necessarily json encode well (date, decimal, etc.) so I don't have much experience with it or what it's capable outside of being a "simpler json" encoder.

What would be an example of something malicious that could be done with it?

Comment: https://medium.com/@shibinbshaji007/using-pythons-pickling-to-explain-insecure-deserialization-5837d2328466

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel "Upgrade to read story".

Comment: the object being unpickled could have globally mutating functions, such as `eval`/`exec`/`os.system`. `pickle` does not check for these. So you could very much end up trying to unpickle data that wipes your data. Note that by "globally mutating", I mean functions/expressions that have side effects impacting the environment running the code.

Comment: Sorry! I was able to read it without problems (no subscription or login). The point was that it's easy to find examples of this.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel cool, maybe want to post one or two examples in an answer so this can be useful and isn't behind a paywall?

Answer (score 2):

Like Chase said, functions can be executed by unpickling. According to this source: https://intoli.com/blog/dangerous-pickles/, pickled objects are actually stored as bytecode instructions which are interpreted on opening (similar to Python itself). By writing pickle bytecode, it's possible to make a pickle "program" to do anything.

Here I made a pickle program to run the bash command `say "malicious code"`, but you could run commands like `rm -rf /` as well.

I saved the following bytecode to a file:

```
c__builtin__
exec
(Vimport os; os.system('say "malicious code"')
tR.
```

and then unpickled it with:

```
import pickle
loadfile = open('malicious', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(loadfile)
```

I immediately heard some "malicious code".